# Solr : deleted records reappear in index

Tags: solr, lucene, spring-data-solr

- I have created a CRUD application with Solr using for searching records and spring solr data is used to interact with Solr.
- when when the application starts up I add data to solr index. 
  After starting up I delete a record from the index via Spring `SolrCrudRepository`
- Below is the code for the Repository

  ```
   public interface SolrRentRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<SolrRent, String> {

        SolrRent findById(String id, Sort sort);    
        List<SolrRent> findAll(Sort sort);
  }
  ```
- Below is the `delete` function for deleting solr documents

  ```
  public void unindexRent(Rent rent) {
     if (rent == null || rent.getId() == null) {
        LOGGER.error("Invalid Rent object to unindex : " + String.valueOf(rent));
        throw new RentsException("Invalid Rent object to unindex : " + String.valueOf(rent));
    }
    rentRepository.delete(rent.getId());
    LOGGER.info("Unindexed rent : " + rent);
  }
  ```
- When I search the index After deleting, the deleted record appears.
- If I insert a record using the application and delete it right after that, then the record doesn't reappear in the index.
- Below is the solr document that I'm trying to delete.

  ```
  public class SolrRent {

    @Field
    private String id;    
    @Field
    private String city;    
    @Field
    private String province;    
    @Field
    private String country;    
    @Field
    private String type;    
    @Field(value = "airCondition")
    private boolean hasAirCondition;    
    @Field(value = "garden")
    private boolean hasGarden;    
    @Field(value = "pool")
    private boolean hasPool;    
    @Field
    private boolean closeToBeach;    
    @Field
    private double dailyPrice;    
    @Field
    private int roomsNumber;    
    @Field
    private Date lastModified;

    // getters & setters
  }
  ```
- Solr `schema.xml`

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <schema name="rents" version="1.5">
      <types>
          <fieldType name="string" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true">
              <analyzer>
                  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
                  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
              </analyzer>
          </fieldType>
          <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" />
          <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
          <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
          <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
      </types>

      <fields>
          <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
          <field name="city" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
          <field name="province" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
          <field name="country" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
          <field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
          <field name="signatureField" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" />

          <field name="airCondition" type="boolean" indexed="true" required="true"/>
          <field name="garden" type="boolean" indexed="true" required="true"/>
          <field name="pool" type="boolean" indexed="true" required="true"/>
          <field name="closeToBeach" type="boolean" indexed="true" required="true"/>

          <field name="dailyPrice" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>

          <field name="roomsNumber" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>

          <field name="lastModified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>


          <defaultSearchField>type</defaultSearchField>
      </fields>

      <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  </schema>
  ```

  - solrconfig.xml

LUCENE_48
    data
    
    
    
    
        native

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="deDupChain">
    <processor class="solr.processor.SignatureUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <bool name="enabled">true</bool>
        <str name="signatureField">signatureField</str>
        <bool name="overwriteDupes">true</bool>
        <str name="fields">id</str>
        <str name="signatureClass">solr.processor.Lookup3Signature</str>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>

<query>
    <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>
    <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache" size="512" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0" />
    <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache" size="512" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0" />
    <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache" size="512" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0" />
    <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>
    <queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>
    <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>
    <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>
    <maxWarmingSearchers>2</maxWarmingSearchers>
</query>
<requestDispatcher handleSelect="false">
    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true" multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000" formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048" />
    <httpCaching never304="true" />
</requestDispatcher>
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="sort">title asc</str>
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <int name="rows">10</int>
        <str name="q">*:*</str>
        <bool name="facet">false</bool>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>

<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="update.chain">deDupChain</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>

<requestHandler name="/analysis/field" startup="lazy" class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" />
<requestHandler name="/analysis/document" class="solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler" startup="lazy" />
<requestHandler name="/admin/" class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />
<requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
    <lst name="invariants">
        <str name="q">*:*</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">all</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
<admin>
    <defaultQuery>*:*</defaultQuery>
</admin>
```

- **pastebin** [link](http://pastebin.com/YMviSH8w) for the `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml` files
- Solr version : **4.10.4**

**EDIT**

- No manual commits were issued after inserting/deleting records.
- Below is the solr log that I get when I insert a record through the running app, search it and delete it immediately.

> 196228 [qtp1856056345-12] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  – [collection1]
>   webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=javabin&version=2}
>   {delete=[31b31c84-9e91-45cc-9b41-f22facbf8157]} 0 1 196235
>   [qtp1856056345-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler  – start
>   commit{,optimize=false,openSearcher=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=false,prepareCommit=false}
>   197794 [qtp1856056345-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  –
>   SolrDeletionPolicy.onCommit: commits: num=2
>     commit{dir=NRTCachingDirectory(MMapDirectory@/home/tharindu/Documents/apps/solr-4.10.4/example/solr/collection1/data/index
>   lockFactory=NativeFSLockFactory@/home/tharindu/Documents/apps/solr-4.10.4/example/solr/collection1/data/index;
>   maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0),segFN=segments_d,generation=13}
>     commit{dir=NRTCachingDirectory(MMapDirectory@/home/tharindu/Documents/apps/solr-4.10.4/example/solr/collection1/data/index
>   lockFactory=NativeFSLockFactory@/home/tharindu/Documents/apps/solr-4.10.4/example/solr/collection1/data/index;
>   maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0),segFN=segments_e,generation=14}
>   197795 [qtp1856056345-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  –
>   newest commit generation = 14 197796 [qtp1856056345-12] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher  – Opening
>   Searcher@5fcf2379[collection1] main 197797 [qtp1856056345-12] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler  – end_commit_flush 197797
>   [searcherExecutor-6-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  –
>   [collection1] Registered new searcher Searcher@5fcf2379[collection1]
>   main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_1:31:nrt _a(4.10.4):C10)} 197800
>   [qtp1856056345-12] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  – [collection1]
>   webapp=/solr path=/update
>   params={waitSearcher=true&commit=true&softCommit=false&wt=javabin&version=2} {commit=} 0 1565 203103 [qtp1856056345-12] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – UnInverted multi-valued field
>   {field=type,memSize=4476,tindexSize=48,time=0,phase1=0,nTerms=5,bigTerms=1,termInstances=7,uses=0}
>   203104 [qtp1856056345-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  –
>   [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/select
>   params={q=city:*Badulla*+AND+country:(*Sri*+*Lanka*)+AND+province:*Uva*&facet.limit=10&facet.field=type&sort=city+asc&facet.mincount=1&facet=true&wt=javabin&version=2}
>   hits=0 status=0 QTime=18

- Below is the solr log when I try to search and delete a record that I've added on startup.

> 378758 [qtp1856056345-13] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  –
>   [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/select
>   params={q=city:*city66*&facet.limit=10&facet.field=type&sort=city+asc&facet.mincount=1&facet=true&wt=javabin&version=2}
>   hits=2 status=0 QTime=6  383571 [qtp1856056345-13] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  – [collection1]
>   webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=javabin&version=2}
>   {delete=[zZC8U]} 0 1 383578 [qtp1856056345-13] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler  – start
>   commit{,optimize=false,openSearcher=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=false,prepareCommit=false}
>   383745 [qtp1856056345-13] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  –
>   SolrDeletionPolicy.onCommit: commits: num=2
>     commit{dir=NRTCachingDirectory(MMapDirectory@/home/tharindu/Documents/apps/solr-4.10.4/example/solr/collection1/data/index
>   lockFactory=NativeFSLockFactory@/home/tharindu/Documents/apps/solr-4.10.4/example/solr/collection1/data/index;
>   maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0),segFN=segments_e,generation=14}
>     commit{dir=NRTCachingDirectory(MMapDirectory@/home/tharindu/Documents/apps/solr-4.10.4/example/solr/collection1/data/index
>   lockFactory=NativeFSLockFactory@/home/tharindu/Documents/apps/solr-4.10.4/example/solr/collection1/data/index;
>   maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0),segFN=segments_f,generation=15}
>   383745 [qtp1856056345-13] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  –
>   newest commit generation = 15 383747 [qtp1856056345-13] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – SolrIndexSearcher has not changed -
>   not re-opening: org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher 383747
>   [qtp1856056345-13] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler  –
>   end_commit_flush 383747 [qtp1856056345-13] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  – [collection1]
>   webapp=/solr path=/update
>   params={waitSearcher=true&commit=true&softCommit=false&wt=javabin&version=2} {commit=} 0 170 389109 [qtp1856056345-13] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [collection1] webapp=/solr
>   path=/select
>   params={q=city:*city66*&facet.limit=10&facet.field=type&sort=city+asc&facet.mincount=1&facet=true&wt=javabin&version=2}
>   hits=2 status=0 QTime=5  Appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are performing **commit** after records deletion?

Comment: If you insert the record using application, are u able to search it, before deleting it?  "when when the application starts up I add data to solr index."  How are you adding data to solr in the beginning?  Your solrconfig is missing autoCommit tag. Like Zahid mentioned below are you performing commits after inserting  / deleting data using SolrCrudRepository? By default if the autoCommit tag is missing, no commits will be performed. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UpdateHandlers+in+SolrConfig#Commits

Comment: - Yes I'm able to search it before deleting. 
- At start up I add records using `@postConstruct` bean event listener method. Basically records are added in the same way at startup and after startup, as I have mentioned in the question. 
- No I didn't perform any commits and no `autoCommit` config is added to the `solrconfig.xml`

Comment: @jay: I've added some solr logs for the distinct scenarios. Please take a look.